# Prove or disprove: If $A$ and $B$ are denumerable, then $A - B$ is denumerable

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Prove or disprove: If $A$ and $B$ are denumerable, then $A - B$ is denumerable

Can someone give me a hint as to how to prove/disprove this? My instinct tells me that the claim is true. But I'm stumped as to how to go about proving it.

Comment: Hint: It is not true, think of an extreme example.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How about let $A$ be $\mathbb{N}$ and let $B$ be $\mathbb{Z}$ then $A - B$ is $\varnothing$? Would that work?

Comment: Don't over-complicate. What is the absolutely *simplest* example you can think of?

Comment: @Adrian: Sure, a good one. You can get non-empty sets with $A=1,2,3,\dots$, $B=2,3,4,\dots$.

Comment: We should agree on a definition of denumerability first. Should finite sets be denumerable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As A-B is a subset of A, A-B is denumerable.